# Package does not show on the front-end in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I try to create a package but for some reason, I cannot access the front-end.
This is my package structure, from the project root directory:

```
/package/contact/src/routes/web.php
/package/contact/composer.json
/package/contact/ContactServiceProvider
```

The service provider class looks like the following:

```
namespace Sidneylab\Contact;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ContactServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(){
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes/web.php');
    }

    public function register(){
    }
}
```

Composer.json

```
"name": "sidneylab/contact",
"description": "This will send email to admin and send contact query to database",
"type": "library",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Sidney de Sousa",
        "email": "esp.sousa@gmail.com"
    }
],
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Sidneylab\\Contact\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

web.php

```
Route::get('contact', function(){
return "contact";
 });
```

In my main composer.json file I added this:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/",
        "Sidneylab\\Contact\\": "package/contact/src"
    }
},
```

Also, I imported the service provider inside my confi/app.php

```
Sidneylab\Contact\ContactServiceProvider::class
```

Now, when I hit my url/contact it does not return anything. Anything I could have possibly missed?

Anything to do with the things I named?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your logs? Also I notice that you load the `Sidneylab\\Contact\\` from `package/contact/src` but your serviceprovider is located one folder above that. Meaning it will not be loaded with psr-4

Comment: no errors at all

Comment: And where do you call your serviceprovider itself?

Comment: I register the serviceprovider in config/ap.php inside the providers array.